# angular - how do I use two dataSources for material table?

Tags: angular

I have two tables on my site. I want to perform a single sql query to a database and split the response to two dataSources based on regex and feed that to the two tables.

```
export class DataTablePopulateComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource_1: dataRow[] = [];
  dataSource_2: dataRow[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'];

  constructor(private service:DataRequestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  public getData() {
    let res = this.service.requestData();
    res.subscribe(responseObject => this.dataSource_1 as dataRow[])
    res.subscribe(responseObject => this.dataSource_2 as dataRow[])
  }

}
```

where do I add the splitting logic in this component code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside the subscription.

> ```
>   this.service.requestData().subscribe(res=>{
>     //split here
>   })
> ```